# Is there a way to get the current yticks in plotly?

Tags: r, plotly

in plotly (R) I have the following problem. If I plot something, often if the data is let's say in the interval [22,43], then the yticks are for example: 25, 30, 35, 40

This is okay but I would like that there is always a tick below the minimum and above the maximum value; so if dtick=5, then I would like to have ticks: 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45

So if I just apply it on one plot, I can easily just set

```
  fig <- fig %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(range=c(20,45))
```

However, I would like this to work on different graphes: What I thought I could do:

1. Get the y ticks that plotly has chosen, let us call it yticks
2. If min(y) is not in the range of y_ticks (i.e. yticks[0] > min(y) ), then adapt the range by setting yticks[0]=yticks[0]-(yticks[1]-yticks[0])

This way, we get one additional tick at the lower range limit and it would be exactly what I want; The same I can do for the upper limit

So my question: Is there a way to get the current yticks in plotly?